# При переходе по определенной ссылке менять <option> в <form>

Tags: javascript, php

Нужно, например, при переходе на site.ru/blog/#news пункт option ненять на selected. И так на каждый option.
Как это можно реализовать?

```
<select>
<option selected value="news">Новости</option>
<option value="articles">Статьи</option>
<option value="popular">Популярное</option>
</select>
```

Comment: через js выставлять нужное значение

Comment: и как это будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код работает, если скрипт с кодом присутствует при загрузке новой страницы.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  document.querySelectorAll("#a option").forEach((o) => {
   
    if(o.getAttribute('value') == window.location.hash.substr(1) ) {
      o.setAttribute('selected', true);
    }
    
    return o;
  });
 
});
```

```html
<select id="a">
<option id="news" selected value="news">Новости</option>
<option id="articles" value="articles">Статьи</option>
<option id="popular" value="popular">Популярное</option>
</select>

<a href="#news">Go To News</a>
<a href="#articles">Go To Articles</a>
<a href="#popular">Go To Popular</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но как его применить к параметру value? Нет возможности записать id в самом option.

Comment: @Lion вообще не понял, что вы спросили. Код работает так: если переходите по странице #news, то выбирается опция с `value=news`, что вы хотите?

Comment: т.е. скрипт же не работает без указания id=""?  Мне нужно, чтоб он работал в <option> без указания айди и классов. У меня нет возможности прописать их для параметра <option>.

Comment: @Lion а вы проверили? скрипту вообще не нужны айди и классы, только айди для `<select>`, чтобы найти элемент, в котором размещаются `<option>`, хотя можно и без id у `select` обойтись, прописав нужный селектор в `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Lion если вам код подходит (`id` у `option` не нужны), будьте добры, подарите галочку

Comment: разобрался. Все работает! Спасибо огромное!